# Selecting Cases from an Array in R

Tags: r

I have a function gentimes(10000) which generates a 10000x2 array of (w1,w2) values, as so:

```
gentimes = function(nreps) 
{ 
  x=c(rexp(nreps,1/5),rexp(nreps,1/5)) 
  x1=min(x) 
  x2=max(x) 
  y1=rexp(nreps,1/4) 
  y2=rexp(nreps,1/4) 
  w1=y1 
  w2 = ifelse(x1+y1>x2,x1+y1-x2+y2,y2) 
  z=array(0,c(nreps,2)) 
  z[,1] = w1 
  z[,2] = w2 
  z 
}
```

I would like to look through the outputs and select the cases for which w1<1 and then draw a histogram of the w2 values for these cases. 
I've tried this:

```
z = gentimes(10000)
for (i in 1:10000)
{
if (z[1,i]<1)
{ 
new_array=array(0,c(10000,2))
new_array[i]=c(z[1,i],z[2,i])
}
new_array
}
```

I'm new to R and struggling to create a new array of the new cases. Very grateful of any help :)

Comment: How about `hist(z[z[,1]<1,2])`  ?

Comment: Hi there, one of the goals of the site is that it serves as a resource. The idea is that questions and answers persist. Please don't delete your question without good reason. Rather, if you found the answers helpful, please upvote them and choose the most helpful one to "accept" by clicking the checkmark in the margin.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(gentimes(10000))
df_filtered <- df[df$V1 < 1, ]
ggplot(df_filtered, aes(x=V2)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I converted the matrix to a dataframe for easier filtering/querying. But then I just filter the 1st column, then summarise the 2nd

```
dat <- gentimes(100000)

dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
dat_filtered <- dat[dat$V1 > 1, ]
hist(dat_filtered$V2)
```

[image]